# How to use WeightedAverage Formula in Ireport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using crosstab in Jasper report(ireport 4.5.1) . I need to do 'Weighted Average' calculation on Rowmeasure.

Can we use WeightedAverage Function in Ireport?

I am using ireport4.5.1

Regards

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation where it was required to calculate the interest value. We did it in the following way. Similary, it can be achieved for any calculation at runtime.

```
<textField> <reportElement.. /> <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[$F{VALUE1}]]></textFieldExpression> </textField>
        <textField> <reportElement ..><textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[$F{VALUE2}]]></textFieldExpression> </textField>
        <textField> <reportElement ../><textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[Interest.calculateIntr($F{VALUE1}, $F{VALUE2})]]></textFieldExpression> </textField>
```

Jave code:

```
public class Interest {
static Double calculateIntr(Double value1,Double value2){
 ...
return interest;
}
```